# Variations: Propagate custom lists programmatically

Tags: 2013, custom-list, variations

I want to propagate my custom list programmatically.We can do it with GUI easily but I want to do it programmatically.

Found the option to make it under Variations (screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: I never got it answered though..

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri That is sometimes the case, unfortunately.

Comment: @BennySkogberg yeah, living with it.. However to the questioner as I mentioned in the comment, I used ListAdded event receiver to programmatically add the list in target variation site

Comment: Thanks arsalan but I don't want to create event receiver. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Can't think of anything else.. Event Receiver seems to be only way of doing it..